# Handling push notifications with Cordova and Pushwoosh when application is closed

Tags: cordova, push-notification

I have a setup made up of Cordova 2.6 and Pushwoosh on iOS. I'm able to receive Push Notifications I send from the Pushwoosh portal. Certificates and SDK work fine now. (But it took a while)

At the moment, when the application is closed, any sent Push Notification appears on the iPhone notification center, but does not increment the application badge, although I read about a "badge auto-incrementing" feature on Pushwoosh website. I cannot figure out how to configure that in the application.

Second point: when launching the application, I'd like to be able to parse the list of "pending notifications", and display them onscreen.

Any idea how to do that? I know an API exists (http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/push-notification-sdk-integration-for-phonegap/), but documentation is almost nonexistent...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to send badges with Pushwoosh, you need to use the "Badges" field in the Advanced form. You can either enter the exact number to be sent, or +1 to increment your badge.

As for the list of pending push notifications, it is being handled by the Notification Center of your OS (iOS or Android), not by the application. If you open the app independently, it cannot know about notifications which were sent to the device; the only way would be to make the app download any required information directly from your server.

Comment: Hi, I finally found the +1 trick for badges in the "advanced form" on your portal. Works just fine, thanks. Still wondering how to add a server to this setup, though. Thanks!